# Edit Template bind on HTML Attribute Kendo UI

Tags: jquery, html, mvvm, kendo-ui

I am pretty much new to Kendo and apparently I am to stupid to find a solution.
I want to build a little Webapp with MVVM which has editable cards built in.
Usually I am able to bind my edit-template with jQuery to a ViewModel.
i.e. like this:

```js
editTemplate: kendo.template($('#cardEditTemplate').html())
```

But I wonder if it's possible to bind the edit template direct in html to the attribute. Something like this:

```html
<div id="board-#: Id #" class="board" data-template="listTemplate" data-bind="source:ListViewModels "></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not like that, you need to bind source and make template that has access to that source, something like this:

```
<div id="users">
    <div data-bind="source: users" data-template="users-template"></div>

    <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="users-template">
        <div>
            <span>#: username #</span> ||<span data-bind="text: username"></span><br>
            <span>#: age #</span> ||<span data-bind="text: age"></span>

        </div>
    </script>

    <button class="k-button" data-bind="click: updateName">Update first name</button>
    <button class="k-button" data-bind="click: updateAge">Update first name</button>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var obs = function () {
            return kendo.observable({
                users: [{id: 1, username: 'Jon', age: 32}, {id: 2, username: 'Jake', age: 22}],
                updateName: function () {
                    this.users[0].set('username', 'updated name');
                },
                updateAge: function () {
                    this.users[1].set('age', '100');
                }
            });

        };

        let viewModel = obs();
        kendo.bind($('#users'), viewModel);
    });
</script>
```

Working example: [Kendo template binding](https://dojo.telerik.com/inoBehUT)

PS. Check difference between `#:#` and `data-bind="text:"` by clicking update buttons

Comment: Thanks. this is not entirely what i am looking for but you gave me an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to dynamical set element attributes.  This is kind of a must when you are binding a collection of data to a "data-template."

A great use case for this would be to set the ID attribute, to help with automation, or to set the FOR attribute to help with the user experience.  Again setting the FOR attribute will help the automation team use a label driven approach making the automation lookup strategy more logical in nature (easier to read).

Below is the code you are looking for:

Label:

```
<label data-bind="attr: { for: LogicalName + '_nameTxt' }" class="" style="white-space:nowrap;">#=LogicalName#:</label>
```

Input:

```
<input data-bind="attr: { id: LogicalName + '_nameTxt' }, value: Value" type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="50" style="width:300px;" />
```

**NOTE**
You must append any additional string.  Prepending is NOT allowed.